# How to get Razor Page Handler Method Name without the "On" Prefix and optional "Async" Suffix?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I wish to get the razor page handler "RAW" method name for use in validating the calling handler method in an OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync of a IAsyncPageFilter implementation in my application with `context.HandlerMethod.Name = rawMethodName`.

I Objectively require this to support working in a **strongly typed manner** and also to make sure the correct handler method is always referenced.

[The Razor Page Framework use a naming convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#write-a-basic-form) to select the appropriate handler method to execute. The default convention works by matching the HTTP method used for the request to the name of the method, which is prefixed with "On" e.g. `OnGet()`, `OnPost()`, `OnPut()` etc. Handler methods also have optional asynchronous equivalents e.g. `OnPostAsync()`, `OnGetAsync()` etc.

I have tried the following method to replace the matching convention using Regex.

```
public string GetRawHandlerMethodName(string handlerMethod)
{
    List<string> namingConventions = new List<string>() { "OnGet", "OnPost", "OnPut", "Async" };
    string handlerMethodName = handlerMethod;
    foreach (string namingConvention in namingConventions)
    {
        string[] result = Regex.Split(handlerMethodName, namingConvention, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        handlerMethodName = string.Join("", result);
    }
    return handlerMethodName;
}
```

I call the method in a strongly typed way as follows:

```
string rawMethodName = GetRawHandlerMethodName(nameof(OnPostMyMethodAsync));
// Output: MyMethod
```

### Use Case

I then use the output for validation in my `IAsyncPageFilter` as follows:

```
public async override Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(PageHandlerExecutingContext context, PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
{
    string rawMethodName = GetRawHandlerMethodName(nameof(OnPostMyMethodAsync));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.HandlerMethod.Name) && context.HandlerMethod.Name == rawMethodName)
    {
        // Calling method is MyMethod. Do work...
    }
}
```

Is there a conventional way of retrieving the handler method name to perform this check? For example how ASP.NET Core gets and sets the name of the `context.HandlerMethod.Name` property similar to what we validate against? Please provide any suggestions or suitable workarounds to this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to map the handler yourself,just compare method name as below:

```
public async override Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(PageHandlerExecutingContext context,
                                                           PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var targetMethod = nameof(OnGet);
        if (context.HandlerMethod?.MethodInfo.Name == targetMethod)
        {
            //do work here
        }
    
        await next.Invoke();
    }
```

Comment: I have tested this, works as expected. I was not aware the [HandlerMethodDescriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.infrastructure.handlermethoddescriptor?view=aspnetcore-8.0) Class had the Name property. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Following [@Ruikai Feng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78031305/23082833), I have created a set of extensions to facilitate validation in the IAsyncPageFilter implementation and any other [Page Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/filter?view=aspnetcore-8.0) implementations you may have in Razor pages. Hope it helps someone.

The following is the extension class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure;
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

public static class HandlerMethodDescriptorExtensions
{
    public static bool IsDefaultGet(this HandlerMethodDescriptor handlerMethod)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(handlerMethod.Name) &&
            handlerMethod.HttpMethod.Equals(HttpMethods.Get, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
    
    public static bool IsDefaultPost(this HandlerMethodDescriptor handlerMethod)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(handlerMethod.Name) &&
            handlerMethod.HttpMethod.Equals(HttpMethods.Post, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
    
    public static bool IsMethodName(this HandlerMethodDescriptor handlerMethod, string handlerMethodName)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(handlerMethod.Name) &&
            handlerMethod.MethodInfo.Name == handlerMethodName;
    }
    
    public static bool IsRawMethodName(this HandlerMethodDescriptor handlerMethod, string handlerMethodName, string httpMethod = HttpMethods.Post)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(handlerMethod.Name) &&
            handlerMethod.Name == handlerMethodName &&
            handlerMethod.HttpMethod.Equals(httpMethod, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

To validate in a in a strongly typed manner I use the `IsMethodName(,)` extension, as follows:

```
// Strongly-typed check, ensure OnPostMyMethodAsync handler exists
if (context.HandlerMethod.IsMethodName(nameof(OnPostMyMethodAsync)))
{
    // Implementation logic
}
```

And to validate using the raw string based text, I use the `IsRawMethodName(,)` extension, as follows:

```
// Simple check, no need to prefix the string with OnPost or Async suffix
if (context.HandlerMethod.IsRawMethodName("MyMethod")))
{
    // Implementation logic
}
```

To validate the default OnGet(), OnPost() handler methods, I simply use the extensions `IsDefaultGet()` and `IsDefaultPost()` respectively without supplying any parameters, as follows:

```
if (context.HandlerMethod.IsDefaultGet())
{
    // Implementation logic
}
if (context.HandlerMethod.IsDefaultPost())
{
    // Implementation logic
}
```

Comment: The Defaults' methods is a Clever thought. Nice! I would probably name the extensions as `IsMethodInfoName` and `IsMethodName` to match with those of Asp.Net Core